# Python Pandas add column with relative order numbers

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

How do I add a order number column to an existing DataFrame?

This is my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import math
frame = pd.DataFrame([[1, 4, 2], [8, 9, 2], [10, 2, 1]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

def add_stats(row):
    row['sum'] = sum([row['a'], row['b'], row['c']])
    row['sum_sq'] = sum(math.pow(v, 2) for v in [row['a'], row['b'], row['c']])
    row['max'] = max(row['a'], row['b'], row['c'])
    return row

frame = frame.apply(add_stats, axis=1)
print(frame.head())
```

The resulting data is:

```
    a  b  c  sum  sum_sq  max
0   1  4  2    7      21    4
1   8  9  2   19     149    9
2  10  2  1   13     105   10
```

First, I would like to add 3 extra columns with order numbers, sorting on sum, sum_sq and max, respectively. Next, these 3 columns should be combined into one column - the mean of the order numbers - but I do know how to do that part (with apply and axis=1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for `rank` where you mention `sorting`. Given your example, add:

```
frame['sum_order'] = frame['sum'].rank()
frame['sum_sq_order'] = frame['sum_sq'].rank()
frame['max_order'] = frame['max'].rank()

frame['mean_order'] = frame[['sum_order', 'sum_sq_order', 'max_order']].mean(axis=1)
```

To get:

```
    a  b  c  sum  sum_sq  max  sum_order  sum_sq_order  max_order  mean_order
0   1  4  2    7      21    4          1             1          1    1.000000
1   8  9  2   19     149    9          3             3          2    2.666667
2  10  2  1   13     105   10          2             2          3    2.333333
```

The rank method has some options as well, to specify the behavior in case of identical or NA-values for example.